# How long it will take the inapp purchase pending status change to success In Apple purchase history

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

[image: Inapp pending in users purchase history]

It is a question regarding my application in-app purchase pending. I am using store kit delegate function and  code as shown below

```
for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {

    switch (transaction.transactionState)

    {

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            [self completeTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            [self failedTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:

            [self DefferedTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

            [self PurchasingTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        default:

            break;

    }

};
```

Then I get a pending transaction . and I update my server database with temporary value. But I want to know when the pending transaction becomes a success.

Comment: Am also stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was quite interesting that I have run about one week behind the inApp pending issue . And I got an answer from apple side that is when we deal the inapp purchase with the below code `for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {

```
switch (transaction.transactionState)

{

    case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

        [self completeTransaction:transaction];

        break;

    case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

        [self failedTransaction:transaction];

        break;

    case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

        [self restoreTransaction:transaction];

    case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:

        [self DefferedTransaction:transaction];

        break;

    case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

        [self PurchasingTransaction:transaction];

        break;

    default:

        break;

}
```

when a transaction is happen without any failure it will get SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased state and we can proceed the applications process with success methods And no need to worry about the pending transaction apple consider this as success transaction and within 48 hours the amount will credit into the account.